# Filtering for an array of structural data with BigQuery, Python API

Tags: python, sql, google-bigquery, google-analytics

I am currently working my way through BigQuery and the python API. I want to export data to a pandas data frame, filtering for structural data. My *table* in Google Cloud looks like this:

```
Report-Date Contract Specification  Value
2020-01-01  A        1              34.2
2020-01-01  A        2              37.2
2020-01-01  A        3              39.7
2020-01-02  A        1              34.1
2020-01-02  A        2              37.0
2020-01-02  A        3              38.8
2020-01-01  B        1              10.0
2020-01-02  B        2              10.1
2020-01-01  C        2              74.7
2020-01-01  C        2              75.2
2020-01-02  C        3              80.9
2020-01-02  C        3              80.9
```

Now I want to find a way to extract all data with certain combinations of Contract and Specification. E.g. all data points for contract A with specification 1 or 2, all data points for contract B with specification 1 and all data points for contract C with specification 3. In the end, I want to have a *pandas dataframe* like this:

```
Report-Date Contract Specification  Value
2020-01-01  A        1              34.2
2020-01-01  A        2              37.2
2020-01-02  A        1              34.1
2020-01-02  A        2              37.0
2020-01-01  B        1              10.0
2020-01-02  C        3              80.9
2020-01-02  C        3              80.9
```

To that end I wanted to create an ArrayClassParameter of structs<string,int64> as a variable in a query. It should somehow look like the following, but I know, that my query_parameters are wrong. I don't know how to handle StructQueryParameter.

```html
query = """
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE STRUCT(Contract, Specification) in @product;
"""

query_parameters = [
    bigquery.ArrayQueryParameter("product", "STRUCT<STRING, INT64>", [(A,1), (A,2), (B,1), (C,3)]),
]

job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(
    query_parameters = query_parameters
)

query_job = client.query(query, job_config=job_config)  # Make an API request.

while query_job.state != 'DONE':
    time.sleep(1)
    print("The query is still running")

if query_job.state == 'DONE':
    df=query_job2.to_dataframe()
    print(df)
```

I know how to use the ArrayQueryParameter with non-structural data and filter for a list of structs in BigQuery itself, but I'm struggling with this.

I also know that I just can iterate over a list of that structural data in python, running a query in every iteration. But I think the performance will get worse.

Every help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Could you maybe add an example and how are you planning what the data would look like?

Comment: I put some additional information in my question.